# QNAP 4 bay TS-451 creating volume in newly added drives

Tags: raid-1, qnap

I just recently bought a four bay QNAP TS-451 which I set up with 2x6TB drives in RAID1. I moved my library and now I want to add 2x3TB drives also in RAID1 but in a new volume.

Which are the steps to create the new volume without touching the data you already have? (Shame on me I cannot find it on the manual ...)

Comment: User manual here: https://www.qnap.com/en-uk/support/con_show.php?cid=11